# Stop recurring jQuery elements by Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to add certain elements through jQuery within a form that involves auto Ajax requests every 5s. I choose `ajaxComplete()` in order to fire off the jQuery elements when the form is loaded. Due to these repetitive ajax requests, the added elements by jQuery are being pushed every 5s into the form. How do I avoid this?

```
$(document).ajaxComplete( function() {
    // jQuery Actions ( .insertAfter, .prependTo )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementAdded = false;
$(document).ajaxComplete( function() {
    if(!elementAdded){
        //add elements
        //...
        elementAdded = true
    }
}):
```

Comment: I have added this, but it's not working. No syntax errors, but it's just not doing anything, I think it's not picking up the variable

Comment: Normally the code should be executed after every ajax call. I suggest using the developer tools (F12) to be able to debug the code.

Comment: I am aware of the debig method, but there's nothing related. Maybe I just executed it incorrect. I added the current full code in my Q.

Comment: And what code are you using to perform the ajax call?

Comment: it's done by a plugin, it collects the latest comments in one overview. WP Review Pro